# How to retrieve many to many relationships in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, many-to-many, dynamics-crm-2011, relationship

In my silverlight application, I'm trying to retrieve my related entities in a many to many relationship in CRM 2011. I tried to follow several examples like [this](http://inogic.com/blog/?p=94) but they required the use of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll assembly which I cannot reference in Silverlight.

Is there any way I can do it in silverlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware that I can use FetchXML to do that. I created my query on Advanced find and downloaded the FetchXML